# error using static method in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, static, c++14, gcc6

I have a `static` method `my_method_1()` in `my_class`, and I am trying to use it in a lambda:

```
static void my_method_1(el);

void my_class::my_method_2()
{
    std::for_each(my_list_.begin(), my_list_.end(),
        [](auto& element)
        {
            my_method_1(element);
        });
}
```

gcc6 gives me an error:

> 'this' was not captured for this lambda function

In gcc4, it compiles.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where is the implementation of the `my_method_1(element)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce.

According the error ("error: ‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function") `my_method_1()` isn't `static`.

If `my_method_1()` is a non-static method, you can use it inside a lambda capturing `this` by value (that is like capturing the object by reference); something like

```
 //  v <- capture by value 
    [=](auto& element)
     { my_method_1(element); }
```

If `my_method_1()` is really a `static` method, please prepare a minimal but complete example to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

2 observations:

1. your function is static, you can refer to it as `my_class::my_method_1()`
2. You don't need to use a lambda here, have you tried this ?

   ```
   void my_class::my_method_2()
   {
       for (auto& element : my_list)
           my_method_1(element);
   }
   ```